# firebase database how to know if parent exist?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've the following scenario:

One user can have several photos, each photo can be reported by other users for violating the term of the app

So i do something like:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("reports").child(ownerId).child(g.getMediaId()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
...
...
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) { //do stuff 
 }
}
```

The point is `dataSnapshot.exists()` returns if the whole branch exists... it may not exist because the `mediaID` is new (first report of that photo) or because the whole `ownerId` branch is new (first report of any photo of that user)

how can i know if the parent exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize what I understand:

- You have a JSON tree `/reports/$ownerid/$mediaid`.
- You attach a listener to a specific `/reports/ownerid/mediaid`.
- You want to check if the `ownerid` exists.

A listener gets all the data underneath the level where you attach it, but it gets no data from levels above where it is attached. So the only way to determine if `/reports/ownerid` exists, is to attach a listener on that level.

Note that this will then download **all** data under that `/reports/ownerid`, which may be more than you need. If that is the case, consider keeping a separate list of `known_owners`, where you track which owners you have data for.

Comment: one question that is not going to change nothing... why doesn't google provide something for the android api like `shallow` that is available for the rest api?